# Non-boolean logical OR operator

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

In some languages you can use the logical OR operator to do something like

```
return x || 'default'
```

Which will return `x` if `x` evaluates to something that is considered 'truthy', but returns `'default'` if x is falsy (`false` or `0` for example).

This is functionally equivalent to `return x ? x : 'default'` in ternary and `=if(x, x, "default")` in spreadsheets, but without the need to repeat `x`. Is there anything equivalent to the aforementioned `this or that` notation that does not require repeating `x` and does not introduce extra columns?

---

Note on Microsoft Excel: I am aware of the Microsoft excel `let()` function which still requires repeating `x` twice, but allows `x` to be something complex. I am instead looking for something as simple as `=DEFAULT(value1, default)` or `=LOR(value1, value2)`.

Note on Google Sheets: I am aware that I can define an absolutely trivial `LOR` function using the script editor, but I have a hard time believing there isn't some native solution.

```
function LOR(a, b) {
  return a || b;
}
```

Comment: The nearest I know is =IFERROR(1/1/x,"default") but it's obviously not great.

Comment: Is this about Excel or about Sheets?

Comment: @Iamblichus Sorry if it was unclear, both Google Sheets and Excel have been tagged and both Google Sheets and Excel are mentioned in the question text. Given the overlap between spreadsheet solutions I was hoping I had just overlooked some basic function/construction/concept. Basically I just didn't want to miss out on Excel-first users who might be able to point me in just as much the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand exactly your question but that would solve your problem?

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(A1="";"false";ISERROR(A1));B1;A1);B1)
```

Comment: You just repeated A1 three times and B1 two times... I am looking for something that's functionally similar/equivalent to the Google sheet script editor function I mentioned at the end. So something like `IFERROR` but instead just `IFANYTHING(conditionAndReturnValue, otherwise)`

Comment: I think it's possible only with lambda formulas, available from Excel 365. Check this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/blog/lambda-the-ultimatae-excel-worksheet-function/

Comment: I totally forgot about those and you're absolutely right that would be the equivalent I think of the custom script in Google Sheets. Still pretty neat.